# Android check service state such as start/stop

Tags: android

By this below code i want to check service state such as start or stop, but this method always return false and i can't check that

```
public static boolean isServiceRunning(Context context, String className) {
    boolean isRunning = false;
    ActivityManager activityManager
            = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(
            Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> servicesList
            = activityManager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo si : servicesList) {
        if (className.equals(si.service.getClassName())) {
            isRunning = true;
        }
    }
    return isRunning;
}
```

i have simple `Service` as `DownloadFile` and with

```
boolean state = isServiceRunning("DownloadFile");
```

I'm trying to check and test that

Comment: Try it with `si.service.getSimpleName()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one like following:

```
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And call it by using: `isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class)`

Comment: Thanks, please let me to test that sir.

Comment: @mahdipishguy check it out :)